# What's the difference of (require 'init-local nil t) and (require 'init-local)?

Tags: require

I'm not familiar with elisp at present.

I put my local configuration into init-local.el and exclude it in .gitignore.

I use `(require 'init-local nil t)` in [init.el](https://github.com/ji-zhou/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el) file before, however I think `(require 'init-local)` could have the same effect when I review my init.el today.

So I have the question : What's the difference of `(require 'init-local nil t)` and `(require 'init-local)` ?

;;; update

Thanks @phils and @DoMiNeLa10, after your comment and answer, I understand that it must be `(require 'init-local nil t)` because the file init-local.el is optional, if I use `(require 'init-local)` and the file init-local.el is missing I will get the error:

> File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, init-local

Comment: `C-h f require`

Comment: What @phils said - *ask Emacs*. Also: **`C-h i`**, choose Elisp, **`require`** takes you to the Elisp manual, node [Named Features](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html), which tells you everything about `require`. Also, `C-h r load` takes you to the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html), which covers loading Lisp libraries in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` takes following arguments:

```
(require FEATURE &optional FILENAME NOERROR)
```

The `NOERROR` argument causes the function to return `nil` when file with the feature isn't found. Without that argument set to `t`, you'd get an error.